# Using "this" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use vanilla Javascript to change the color of an  tag whenever it is clicked using the "this" keyword. The element starts out as red. If it's clicked while it's red, then it changes to green. If it's clicked while it's green, it changes to blue. If it's clicked while it's blue, then it changes to red.

It seems simple enough, and according to my resources my code should be working, but it's not. What am I missing here?

Here's my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeColor(obj) {

    if (obj.style.backgroundColor=="#ff0000") {

            obj.style.backgroundColor="#00ff00";

        } else if (obj.style.backgroundColor=="#00ff00") {

            obj.style.backgroundColor="#0000ff";

        } else {

            obj.style.backgroundColor="#ff0000";

        }
    }
</script>
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<a style="background-color: #ff0000;" onclick="changeColor(this)" href="#">Click me</a>
```

I think that this question is relevant to people who are just learning how to use the "this" keyword.

Thanks!

Comment: @CBroe *Not* a duplicate of this question. At all.

Comment: [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is nothing to do with `this`, and everything to do with how colours are stored in the browser.

Clearly, you didn't try basic debugging, as `alert(obj.style.backgroundColor)` would have clearly revealed what was going on.

You would be better off saving your own property. For example:

```
function changeColor(obj) {
    obj.__color = ((obj.__color || 0)+1)%3;
    switch(obj.__color) {
        case 0: obj.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000"; break;
        case 1: obj.style.backgroundColor = "#00ff00"; break;
        case 2: obj.style.backgroundColor = "#0000ff"; break;
    }
}
```

[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pJG3b/)

Comment: Not sure why this answer was downvoted. The jsfiddle shows it working perfectly.

Comment: he is setting the `backgroud-color` by checking the `click count` not checking the `background-color` and set the `color`

Comment: @jhyap I'm sorry, am I missing something? I thought the idea was to make a cyclic background colour.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Element.style.backgroundColor returns a color in an RGB format. This code will work:

```
var changeColor = function (obj) {
  if (obj.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {

      obj.style.backgroundColor = "#00ff00";

  } else if (obj.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(0, 255, 0)") {

      obj.style.backgroundColor = "#0000ff";

  } else {

      obj.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";

  }
}
```

However, consider keeping your own reference to the current color. For example:

```
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"], ind = 0;
var changeColor = function (obj) {
    ind++;
    ind %= colors.length;
    obj.style.backgroundColor = colors[ind];
}
```

Comment: Assuming, of course, that the browser chooses to use that format and not one of infinitely many others (hex, hsl, rgba, colour name, rgb but with arbitrarily variable whitespace...)